# Just need some help for an head-scratching bug in python 3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

Versions: 
Python 3.10.4 (main, Mar 31 2022, 08:41:55) [GCC 7.5.0] on linux

I made some functions for parsing and formatting data before store it. 
Here a short example of the "raw" data and expected formats :

```
#"field": (['raw data '], [expected result])
"name": (["JACK OF TRADES ", "MI C'INFILO  "], ["jack of trades", "mi c'infilo"]),
"gender": (["F", "h", "M"], ["f", "h", "m"]),
"weight": (["51", "54,5", None], [51.0, 54.5, 0.0]),
```

`name` and `gender` are `str` format, and `weight` is `float` format. To apply it I made those functions:

```
# Functions for formatting #
def format_string(contenu: str or None): #  contenu means content
    if isinstance(contenu, str):
        contenu = contenu.lower().strip()
    return contenu

def format_numerique(contenu: str or None):
    if isinstance(contenu, str):
        if contenu.replace(".", "").replace(",", "").isdigit():
            if "." in contenu:  
                contenu = float(contenu.replace(".", ""))
            else:  
                contenu = float(contenu.replace(",", "."))
        else:
            contenu = contenu
    else:  # None
        contenu = 0.0
    return contenu

#Function for applying the right format to the right field

def formatage(field: str, contenu: str or list):
    formats = {
        ("weight"): format_numerique,
        ("name", "gender"): format_string,    
    }
    # right key choice
    keys = formats.keys()
    right_key = None
    for key in keys:
        if field in key:
            right_key = key
    # apply format if required
    if right_key:
        fonc_format = formats[right_key]
        if isinstance(contenu, list):
            print('LIST!') # for debugging
            [print(i) for i in contenu]  # for debugging
            for i in contenu:  # for debugging
                print(fonc_format(i))  # for debugging
            contenu = [fonc_format(i) for i in contenu]
        elif isinstance(contenu, str):
            print('STR!')  # for debugging
            contenu = fonc_format(contenu)
    print("DONE!") # for debugging
    return contenu
```

For reasons I don't manage to find, the field `gender` acts with unexpected results:

```
>>>formatage("gender", ["F", "h", "M"])
LIST!
F
h
M
h
h
h
DONE!
['h', 'h', 'h'] # unexpected, must be ["f", "h", "m"]
```

I checked the root: the formatting function itself

```
>>>format_string("F")
'f' # as expected
```

I checked the applying function

```
>>>formatage("name",["JACK OF TRADES ", "MI C'INFILO  "])
LIST!
JACK OF TRADES 
MI C'INFILO  
jack of trades
mi c'infilo
DONE!
['jack of trades', "mi c'infilo"] # as expected

>>>formatage("name", ["F", "h", "M"]) # writing wrong field purposely
LIST!
F
h
M
f
h
m
DONE!
['f', 'h', 'm'] # expected result but with the wrong field
```

I don't see any reason why it becomes messy with the field `gender`.

Comment: Do you really want `formats` to have a tuple for a key?

Comment: I dont see any issue with the code. When i try to execute your code by calling test=formatage("gender", ["F", "h", "M"]), when i print test i am getting ['f', 'h', 'm']. Can you please try once again

Comment: @MarkRansom what is wrong if I use tuple ? What is the incidence ?

Comment: @manjari I tried it many times. That's why I don't know what to do, and it still give this wrong result. I even reboot my IDE console.

Comment: I have found through long experience that when given the choice between a bug in my own code and a bug in the compiler/interpreter, 99.999% of the time it's my code.  That's not an exaggeration.

Comment: OK, I've taken a few minutes to look at the code now.  The tuple works as a key because of the way you get `right_key`, but it's a waste of a dictionary's capabilities.  But it does not explain your problem. In fact I can't explain your problem because it works for me too. Perhaps a copy/paste error, but you need to provide code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @MarkRansom [Here a link for a piece of the real code](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AibRZKV_Ojy5rWAbxxi0TBm-PoQK), but this the same paradigm as I shown in the topic.

Comment: Well that explains it, your posted code is not representative of your real code.  You're calling `format_sexe` not `format_string`, and that function is very particular about its input.

Comment: @MarkRansom No it does not explain and it is totally representative. There is a HUGE difference between `format_sexe` and `format_string` ! This is not applied on the same field ! `sexe` and `conditions_sexe` are totally different in their meaning and their inputs. `sexe` is specific to the horse, `conditions_sexe` is specific to which sex is allowed in the race. So do not tell me I did not apply the right format to right field while you totally ignore their meaning. So ask before getting hasty conclusion.

Comment: The code in your link does not contain the word "gender" in it at all, so I assumed you really meant "sexe" and made the change when you posted the question.  If I assumed incorrectly, I apologize.  Either way, the point still stands that your code in the question does not match your real code, and the problem I identified results in the exact output you complained about.  See https://ideone.com/mtvroq.

Comment: @MarkRansom alright, but why ? There is no visible reason.

Comment: @MarkRansom I did change the word for `gender` because some "helpers" in stackoverflow won't help if the code is not translated with english word.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the way you determine the key to use in your dictionary.

```
    keys = formats.keys()
    right_key = None
    for key in keys:
        if field in key:
            right_key = key
```

If `key` is a tuple, it works as you expect.  If `key` is a string, it checks if `field` is a *substring* of `key` and matches that.  Because you don't terminate the loop, the last match is the one that takes precedence.

You may think that `("weight")` is a tuple, but it isn't - it's a single string.  To make it a tuple requires a comma: `("weight",)`.

The code in the question doesn't have the problem you described but the actual code in your link makes it clear.  The string `"sexe"` matches two keys, `(..., "sexe", ...)` and `"conditions_sexe"`.  The last match wins.

P.S. you could eliminate the problem by doing away with the key finding loop entirely, using the dictionary the way it was meant to be used:

```
   formats = {
        "weight": format_numerique,
        "name": format_string,
        "gender": format_string,    
    }

    fonc_format = formats[field]
```